# How can do I enable onclick to clear an input field? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('<p><input type="text" class = "class-'+ (++i)  +'" onclick="'(+ this.value = ''; +)'" value="Enter Choice #' + i + '"/></p>')
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax or not, but whatever I am using is not working. ANy help? Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Modify an existing element? Create a new element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it inline like that, you need to keep the `this.value=''` as part of the string:

```
$('<p><input type="text" class = "class-'+ (++i) +'" onclick="this.value=\'\'" value="Enter Choice #' + i + '"/></p>');
```

Notice the `" onclick="this.value=\'\'"`, where the single quotes are escaped to keep the main string from being terminated.

[**Here's a working example for you.**](http://jsfiddle.net/usASj/)

Comment: @harrison: You're welcome. If you only want to clear the input when the default value is present, add `if(this.value==this.defaultValue)` to the string. [Updated example.](http://jsfiddle.net/usASj/1/)

Answer (score 5):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="class-1" value="Enter Choice #1">
<input type="text" class="class-2" value="Enter Choice #2">
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[class^="class-"]').focus(function() {
        var $input = $(this);

        if($input.val() == $input.data('default_val') || !$input.data('default_val')) {
            $input.data('default_val', $input.val());
            $input.val('');
        }
    });

    $('input[class^="class-"]').blur(function() {
        var $input = $(this);

        if ($input.val() == '') $input.val($input.data('default_val'));
    });
});
```

Above code clear the value when the textfields gets focus and adds the default value when textfield is empty on lost focus (blur).

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K3Sx7/4/

EDIT: updated code to conform question.

Comment: class needs to remain unchanged, as it is needed for another part of the code

Answer (score 3):

Add an id to your input field:

```
<input id="myinput"...
```

Then add this code in your `$(document).ready(...` call:

```
$('#myinput')                    // get element whose id is 'myinput'
    .click(function() {          // bind a click handler
        $(this).val('')          // clear field
               .unbind('click'); // unbind click handler to avoid field being cleared again
     })
```

Comment: i've tried this also, but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason. it seems logical though. i'm not sure if its because i'm implementing it incorrectly, or not.

Comment: Are you sure you using jQuery? Neither your question nor the accepted answer deal directly with jQuery features. And remember to call the code I wrote after the element is added to the body, otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it without jQuery 
try this

```
<p><input type="text" class = "class-1" onclick="this.value='';" value="Enter Choice # 1"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
$('<input type="text" class="class-'+ ++i +'" value="Enter Choice #' + i + '"/>')
   .click(function(){
       this.value = '';
    })
    .wrap('<p />')
    .parent()
    .appendTo('#container');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jruddell/FVqjQ/

Comment: i've tried this but it doesn't let me add, in my code. i'm not sure how the appendto works.

Comment: i can only remove from the list, i can't add to the list of inputs.

Comment: @harrison - .appendTo(<selector>). If you show some more of your code I can help you integrate the solution.